# PostgreSQL search/index (GIN index?) across two columns/arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-indexes

Let's say we have a PostgreSQL table `contacts`, each record having a bunch of labeled email addresses (pairs of labels and emails) — one of which is the "primary".

This is stored like:

- `id` primary key
- `email` text
- `email_label` text
- `metadata` jsonb

  - `emails` array
  - `email` text
  - `label` text

For example, a record might look something like:

```
id: 1
email: 'a@a.com'
email_label: 'a'
metadata: {
            "emails": [
                        {
                          "email": "b@b.com",
                          "label": "b"
                        },
                        {
                          "email": "c@c.com",
                          "label": "c"
                        }
                      ]
          }
```

Given this storage pattern, we want to be able to find a record by any of its email addresses.

The naive query would look like:

```
SELECT id
FROM contacts
WHERE
  email = 'my@email.com' OR
  metadata -> 'emails' @> '[{"email": "my@email.com"}]'
```

**Is there any way to create an index that speeds up this operation significantly?** It would need to update automatically in response to changes to the records, and ideally index across both the text column and the nested JSONB column.

The specific use case here would be able to do lookups by email address efficiently and quickly, without overhauling this structure or creating a new relational table.

I believe the solution involves using a GIN index and [this question mentions jsonb_path_ops](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127689/how-to-get-particular-object-from-jsonb-array-in-postgresql) but I'm not sure how to wrangle all the pieces together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX contacts_email_idx
   ON contacts (email);

CREATE INDEX contacts_metadata_emails_idx
   ON contacts USING gin ((metadata -> 'emails') jsonb_path_ops);
```

Then the query will be fast, because the indexes match the two conditions exactly and can be combined using a bitmap index scan.

```
EXPLAIN (COSTS off)
SELECT id
FROM contacts
WHERE email = 'my@email.com'
   OR metadata -> 'emails' @> '[{"email": "my@email.com"}]';

                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                         
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on contacts
   Recheck Cond: ((email = 'my@email.com'::text) OR ((metadata -> 'emails'::text) @> '[{"email": "my@email.com"}]'::jsonb))
   ->  BitmapOr
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on contacts_email_idx
               Index Cond: (email = 'my@email.com'::text)
         ->  Bitmap Index Scan on contacts_metadata_emails_idx
               Index Cond: ((metadata -> 'emails'::text) @> '[{"email": "my@email.com"}]'::jsonb)
(7 rows)
```